# before_filter in few controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, before-filter

I would like use one `before_filter` named  `:realtor_suscriber` in few specific actions in the following controllers :

```
realtors/registrations_controller.rb
realtors/sessons_controller.rb
pro/messages_controller.rb
pro/users_controller.rb
```

I defined realtor_suscriber like that in `realtors/registrations_controller.rb`

```
def realtor_suscriber!
....my code here...
end
```

Of course, it doesnt work with action in other controllers (for example pro/messages_controller.rb)

I dont want define realtor_suscriber in application_controller.rb because i've some other controllers they doesnt need this `before_filter` and i would like avoid to use `skip_before_filter` in all the other controllers.

Thanks for advance,

F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the `realtor_suscriber!` method in `ApplicationController` and add

```
before_filter :realtor_suscriber!
```

in those controllers, where you need it.

Comment: Thank you Anton, i'm so stupid... I was looking for a too complicated solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You could define it in the application controller skipping specific controllers

```
def realtor_suscriber!
  if (params[:controller]=="posts" && %w(new edit show).include?(params[:action])) ||
     (params[:controller]=="comments" && %w(create update destroy).include?(params[:action])) ||
     (params[:controller]=="reviews" && %w(like share tweet).include?(params[:action]))
  return # list out all the controller/action pairs which needs to be skipped.
  #....your code here...
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Satya Kalluri, but how to specify the actions in which I want to use for each controller ? Or the specific action in which I dont want use the before filter.

Comment: Use params[:controller[ and params[:action] with if-else to achieve what you want.

Comment: Updated the response. check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
before_filter :realtor_suscriber!, :only => [:abc, :pqr]
#Where abc, pqr are the methods for which you want filter
```

OR

```
before_filter :realtor_suscriber!, :except => [:xyz, :rst]
#Where xyz, rst are the methods for which you don't want filter
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, just define the method in ApplicationController and use it as filter in sub controllers.

Sub controllers inherits from ApplicationController so they always have access to this method. And you don't need to define such filter in ApplicationController.

Comment: Thank you Billy Chan, as i said to Anton, i'm so stupid... I was looking for a too complicated solution :)